# Aggregate "Max" function in Fetchxml for NVARCHAR

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, fetchxml

I am facing error in converting this SQL Query to fetchxml.
Please Help.

```
SELECT max(territoryidname) from systemuser
```

I tried putting this in `fetchxml- aggregate="max"`.

It is throwing an error :

> MIN or MAX aggregate can not be applied on NVARCHAR.

Comment: Try to cast to varchar first `cast(territoryidname as varchar(max))`

Comment: Thanks for the response.
but still its not working in the fetchxml.